# .not() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla

I have an `a` element containing a `svg` and a string. I want to select only the string with jQuery and `.trim()` it, since it contains whitespace. I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when I try to filter with `.not()`.

I do **not** want to remove the `svg` element, but replace the untrimmed string with the trimmed. So using .html() is probably a bad idea, since it replaces the whole content with the trimmed string.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("p.mod-articles-category-readmore a").each(function() {
    var $str = $(this).html().not("svg");
    $(this).html($.trim($str));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="mod-articles-category-readmore">
  <a class="mod-articles-category-title">
    <svg><!--svg content--></svg>
    <!--whitespace created by Joomla-->  Weiterlesen             
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Does it work if you swap around the methods: `$(this).not("svg").html();`?

Comment: @Andy the error is gone now, but when `console.log()`ing `$str`, the `svg` element is still in there.

Answer (score 0):

It is because .html() returns a string which does not have the not method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p.mod-articles-category-readmore a").each(function() {
      var str = $(this).contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType==3}).text();
      $(this).html(str)
  });
});
```

Instead you can just remove the svg element so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p.mod-articles-category-readmore a svg").remove();
});
```

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is, that while the string gets `.trim()`ed successfully, the `svg` element is removed, even though I still need it.

Comment: @SimonMathewson I think you just have to hide the svg element

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After much playing around I managed to pull the SVG part out and the string into seperate variables:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("p.mod-articles-category-readmore a").each(function() {
      var $svg = $(this).children().first().get(0);
      var $str = $.trim($(this).last().text());
      $html = $str + $svg;
      $(this).html($html);
  });
});
```

Only issue when trying to reinject both back into the DOM, the variable containing the SVG dumps as a jquery object string.

There is a JS fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/df28xhxs/) that might at least get you started.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
.not(svg);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this would mean that `svg` is a variable, which is not the case.

Comment: This will likely yield "svg is not defined".